# Can gedit on mac be used to edit files over ssh?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, ssh, gedit

I use a linux machine at work and a mac at home.  I can ssh from my machine at home to my work machine.  But the only editor that I have access to on the command line then is vi, which I don't like.

Is there a way to use gedit on my mac to edit files remotely over an ssh connection?

This page says that it can be done, but I think that it assumes that you are using gedit on ubuntu.  On my mac (os 10.5.8) I don't have the "bookmark" option when I click "connect to server".

http://thecodecentral.com/2010/04/02/use-gedit-as-remote-file-editor-via-ftp-and-ssh-ubuntu/comment-page-1#comment-50558

Answer (score 1):

[CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/) will allow you to edit files over SSH using the Mac text editor of your choice. I recommend TextWrangler.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -X option when you ssh into your linux machine.  If you haven't already installed X11, it's available as an optional install on your OS X install disc.  With X11 installed, 'ssh -X user@host' starts X11 and you're ready to use gedit.

Alternatively, you can use [Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) to mount your linux machine, through ssh, as a file system.  You can then use an OS X text editor to edit files on the remote machine.

Comment: Depending on your version of OS X you may need to reinstall X11. I had to on Leopard.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) to edit files directly over SSH.

Comment: +1 for `ssh -X`. I used that all the time at university. With Leopard and Snow Leopard, I didn't have to reinstall X - it "just worked".

Comment: gedit via x11-forwarding? the horror ... sshfs is the only solution that makes any sense.

Comment: Thanks, @romainl, that's actually the best solution IMHO. I've been using TextWrangler for 3 years and never noticed it can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Gedit uses gvfs, a virtual filesystem layer which allow him to access files through different protocols, including sftp (which is very probably available if ssh is available). So you're likely already able to use it to edit your remote files with no need to install anything. Just type sftp://youserver/ in the open dialog.

You can also use fuse + sshfs to mount the distant file hierarchy to a local mount point, thus be able to use any application to edit any file. An easy way to do this seems to be through [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/).