# Open file in gedit from terminal (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal, gedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can gedit on mac be used to edit files over ssh?](https://superuser.com/questions/241462/can-gedit-on-mac-be-used-to-edit-files-over-ssh)

I've been able to do this in the past but completely forgot how to call it!

I'm using OSX and looking to edit a file in terminal (over ssh). Istead of using emacs or vim I was able to open the file in gedit. I've seen around the web the open command but I'm sure it wasn't that, and also I keep getting "command not found" when I try to use it anyway. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you SSH'ing *to* or *from* OS X?

Comment: From OSX to debian. I ended up using nano on the server, but I'm sure I've been able to open files up in TextEdit or Gedit before in the past. Even if it was only locally.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible methods:

1. TextEdit or Gedit running locally.

   - Using sshfs: Install MacFUSE, use the `sshfs` command to mount the remote file system locally. There's a GUI named MacFusion, if I remember correctly.
   - Using Gedit's SFTP support. On Linux, Gedit accepts such URLs as `sftp://server/filename`. (But to be honest, I don't even know if the same Gedit works on OS X.)
2. Using Gedit remotely. The SSH protocol supports forwarding of X11 connections, so you can install the program on your Debian server, then connect using `ssh -Y servername` and just run `gedit myfile` over SSH.

   You'll also need to have an X11 server running on OS X (I *think* one is bundled), and X11 forwarding enabled in sshd_config on Debian.

There is [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/241462/can-gedit-on-mac-be-used-to-edit-files-over-ssh) on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about OSX, but between debian machines this normally works

```
ssh -X user@host
```

Otherwise it might not tunnel X.